# JavaMailSenderImpl пустое вложение

Tags: java, spring-mvc, javamail

Всем привет. В коде отправляю с двух разных частей кода письмо. Первый вариант кода (код sendMail) присылает посьмо с вложением пустым, имя файла Noname. Второй вариант кода, никакого вложения не присылает  уже. Не могу понять в чем проблема.

```
public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSenderImpl = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    javaMailSenderImpl.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
    javaMailSenderImpl.setPort(567);
    javaMailSenderImpl.setUsername("************");
    javaMailSenderImpl.setPassword("***********");
    javaMailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties().put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    javaMailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties().put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    javaMailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties().put("mail.debug", "true");
    javaMailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties().put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    javaMailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties().put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    javaMailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties().setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    javaMailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties().setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    javaMailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties().setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    return javaMailSenderImpl;
}
```

Код который присылает вложение:

```
public void sendMail(String to, String userName) throws MessagingException {
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(to + ";", ";,");
    MimeMessage message2 = javaMailSenderImpl.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message2, true);
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
    formatter.format("************* %S в: %s", userName, new Date());
    helper.setTo(tokenizer.nextToken());
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        helper.addCc(tokenizer.nextToken());
    }
    helper.setFrom("**************");
    helper.setSubject(formatter.toString());
    javaMailSenderImpl.send(message2);
}
```

Вызов:

```
utilService.sendMail("*****" , SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName().toString());
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

А вы, случаем, не забываете добавить сам аттач в письмо?

```
    mailSender.send(new MimeMessagePreparator() {
   public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws MessagingException {
     MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
     message.setFrom("me@mail.com");
     message.setTo("you@mail.com");
     message.setSubject("my subject");
     message.setText("my text <img src='cid:myLogo'>", true);
     message.addInline("myLogo", new ClassPathResource("img/mylogo.gif"));
     message.addAttachment("myDocument.pdf", new ClassPathResource("doc/myDocument.pdf"));
   }
 });
```

это пример из доков `MimeMessageHelper`, который вы используете, и в нем сразу видно, что аттач добавляется..

Предугадывая ваш дальнейший вопрос о том, откуда берется "noname" - попробуйте подебажить (или включить дебаг-логи spring`а) код примерно вот тут:

```
MimeMessageHelper#createMimeMultiparts(MimeMessage mimeMessage, int multipartMode)
```

Там как раз выставляется mime-тип, и есть упоминания про аттачменты. Мне без кода сложно предположить, как работает код дальше, но я предполагаю, что аттач остается пустым и Spring (или даже транспортный level) заменяет null на пустой файл с именем "noname".

Comment: разобрался. если не добавляю текст `setText(str)` то создается пустое вложение, не важно, добавляю я вложение или нет. т.е. если я добавляю вложение, но не установлю текст, то приходит 2 вложения, одно мое и одно пустое Noname

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Обязательно должен быть текст установлен